# How to hyperlink a word document with a name like (sc + ab) in the website?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a Word document in the server called (sc + ab) and I want to put a link in my website to it. The link is correct but the reason of getting error is the document name. when I change it, it works well. However, I want to keep the name as it is, so How to hyperlink this document?

My code simply is:

```
<li><span style="font-family: arial; color: #0000ff; font-size: 13px;"><a href="http://pmv/PM/PS&CD/cpod/bp/sccm/sc + ab.doc"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Scope Control Introduction</span></a></span> </li>
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry I mistyped the name of the document. It is (SC+CM 320 702.ppt) so how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[urlencode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the special characters (spaces and +): `sc%20%2B%20ab.doc`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but could you please look at my updated question above.

Comment: @user1395782 `SC%2BCM%20320%20702.doc`. Here's an [online tool you can use to urlencode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Answer (score 1):

Go into Chrome and type in the exact physical path of the file on your server.
e.g.

```
C:\PM\PS&CD\cpod\bp\sccm\sc + ab.doc
```

It should convert it the format you require. i.e.

> ```
> ../sc%20+%20ab.doc
> ```

The `+` is only a special character in a query string.

Edit: Same thing with IE. Type in the physical address into the browser and then right click on the page and goto properties. You will see the address as it should be.

Comment: I am using the Internet Explorer

Comment: Same thing with IE. Type in the physical address into the browser and then right click on the page and goto properties. You will see the address as it should be.